# Not show keyboard capture with window flag FLAG_SECURE

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am adding the following flag to my app:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Sadly the keyboard is still visible and I can still see what the user is inputting when I watch thew playback of the screen recording.

Any idea, how I can stop to the keyboard being captured?

Edit: I don't want to hide the soft keyboard as the user has to enter private information in text fields.

Comment: Since you have no access to this `Window`, you have no way of marking it secure. This is one of [many holes in `FLAG_SECURE`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/06/06/psa-flag-secure-window-leaks.html), though [many of those others can be patched](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/docs/FLAGSECURE.md).

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that the soft keyboard is not counted as part of the window (although it's being shown to enter data into a field that is). A bigger guess is that you can't stop the keyboard being part of the recording, but you _may_ be able to stop it echoing keys as they are pressed (but I don't know how).

Comment: Any solutions to prevent a soft keyboard typing exposure after two years as this vulnerability being known?

Comment: This should be escalated to Google as a security bug. Screen recording via virtual displays can capture the key press hints and if user was editing input credentials, its a security toss.