# Preventing/Disabling Screen Recording

Tags: android, security, android-activity, privacy, screen-capture

I want to prevent screen recording and added some code for this like below. When recording screen, all is black. But when trying to type the password keyboard opens, outside of keyboard is black and all the keyboard touches are visible in record. Is there a way to remove keyboard  from record or preventing screen recording?

```
window.setFlags( WindowManager.LoyoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718825/not-show-keyboard-capture-with-window-flag-flag-secure

Comment: Touches are not drawn on screen by default. It's developer tool so perhaps just turning it off would suffice?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski How to turn it off that touch effects on keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to solve that problem is implement the virtual keyboard using the `button`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it will cost a little.